# Как в DbGrid вывести значение в формате currency?

Tags: delphi

У меня результат запроса, который выводится в `DbGrid`, может быть целым числом, а может быть числом с плавающей точкой. Как сделать, чтобы поле, выводимое в `DbGrid`, выводилось в формате `'00.00'`? То есть в денежном формате.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно открыть редактор полей таблицы двойным щелчком по компоненту TTable (TADOTable), TQuery (TADOQuery), добавить все поля командой контекстного меню Add all fields... и найти в списке нужное денежное поле. У денежных полей TField есть логическое свойство Currency, его нужно поставить в True.

Comment: у меня там не само поле типа currency, а результат агрегатной функции SUM... а поле SUM(Поле денежного типа) не имеет логического свойства Currency

Comment: А сама БД какого формата? Глупо, конечно, но и от этого может зависеть. Если, например, это Access, то можно запрос сделать в нём, а таблицу подрубить к TADOTable.

Answer (score 0):

Тут надо не к DBGrid обращаться, а к процессу создания БД. Если при создании таблицы вы указали тип ЭТОГО поля, как currency, то все должно работать =)

Comment: там такая штука... само поле то имеет тип currency, но... выводится SUM(Поле)... то есть результат агрегатной функции... результат выводится не в формате currency